# Numpy - Raise negative elements to non-integer power

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(42)
data = sorted(stats.norm.rvs(size=1000))
```

I want to raise `data` to the power of 3/4.

I tried:

```
np.power(data, 3/4) # doesn't work because power is not integer
np.float_power(data, 3/4) # returns nan for negative elements
scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power(data, 3/4) # doesn't work because data is 1D array, not matrix
```

How can I do this using numpy?

Comment: You are getting `nan` because you are raising negative numbers to a power of 3/4. You asked "I want to raise data to the power of 3/4.". You can do this by converting your data to a numpy array as `data = np.array(list(sorted(stats.norm.rvs(size=1000))))**(3/4)`. This answers your question. What else is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call, say, `np.power` explicitly; by performing your computations before using `sorted` (or even using `np.sort` instead), we can just use operators:

```
np.sort(data ** (3 / 4))
```

Necessarily, this will give `nan` values because a root of a negative number will be complex, and your array can only handle `floats`.

The solution is therefore to cast it to dtype `np.complex`:

```
data = np.sort(stats.norm.rvs(size=10).astype(np.complex) ** (3 / 4))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[-1.18840462+1.18840462j -0.10707968+0.10707968j -0.09787584+0.09787584j
 -0.05992208+0.05992208j  0.10880864+0.j          0.1484953 +0.j
  0.45161317+0.j          0.78783041+0.j          0.79189574+0.j
  0.93656538+0.j        ]
```

Comment: @EricKim Do you expect complex results?

Comment: it shouldn't, but somehow I get complex numbers. I don't understand why

Comment: @EricKim A root of a negative number will necessarily be complex.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.power(data, 3./4)
```

will result in a float for the power. Since 3/4 will return an int.

Comment: That is true only on Python 2, and in any case does not address the OP's problem of getting `nan`.